# Single quotes around variable value

Tags: bash, azure, variables, gitlab

I'm writing a pipeline in GitLab CI and I have multiple variables defined in GitLab's global variables... One of which contains various special characters which need to be contained by single quotes in order to authenticate successfully (tested using hardcoded values).

So, the variable I'm defining in GitLab is `DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET` and it contains something like: `JSBDbshe66!#12$@a` - I am then exporting this variable to the pipeline stage which requires it like so: `export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`.

I have tried simply adding double and single quotes around this variable but that does not work - As mentioned, when trying this manually on the command line with hardcoded values it only works with single quotes. I have even tried using `\'$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET\'` to no avail.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: what about  export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" ?

Comment: btw why do you think that is a secure password, just use upper and lowercase, and add some extra characters, https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: @on8tom - The password generation is out of my control by my organisation.

Comment: @on8tom I have also tried using double quotes, no luck unfortunately. As mentioned, when I run this manually, it will only work with single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like every other command the assignment of a value to a variable will be parsed by the shell, too. To prevent the shell from parsing the special characters must be "quoted". Single characters can be quoted with the backslash (\), multiple characters can be quoted with single quotes (') or double quotes ("). Within single quotes every character will be taken literally. Double-quoted characters will mostly taken literally, with the main exeption (among some others): variables will be replaced with their contents.

To assign the Value "JSBDbshe66!#12$@a" in the command line it must be single-quoted because of the bang (!) sign (see bash bang for further information):

:~$ DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET='JSBDbshe66!#12$@a'

The command

:~$ echo $DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

gives you the desired output:

JSBDbshe66!#12$@a

To copy this value to another variable just enter in the command line:

ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

Alternatively you can enter:

ARM_CLIENT_SECRET="$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"

to receive the same result. The variable-name between the double quotes will be replaced with the value and finally the shell removes the Quotes. If you put the variable name between single quotes

ARM_CLIENT_SECRET='$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET'

every character between the quotes will be taken literally:

:~$ echo $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

If you quote the single quotes via Backslash

:~$ ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=\'$DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET\'

the value of "$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" will be the same as $DEV_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET with an additional leading and a trailing single quote:

:~$ echo $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

'JSBDbshe66!#12$@a'